# cargo install binary with symlinks

Tags: rust-cargo

I have a crate which compiles into a single binary. After installing the single binary `foo` via `cargo install` I would like to automatically symlink `foo` to `bar` inside `$HOME/.cargo/bin`. Currently I do this manually and was wondering whether this can be done by cargo or whether I should rather use make or a shell script or whatever for this task?